# Thrift types as a Generic

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, thrift, simplify

I'm using Apache thrift which generates Java classes that look like this:

```java
public class MyEvent implements org.apache.thrift.TBase<MyEvent, MyEvent._Fields>
```

I'd like to create a container class that takes a generic that implements TBase. I'd like to write code that looks like this:

(kotlin)

```
val msg = MyContainer<MyEvent>()
```

However, I can't do `class MyContainer<T: TBase>` as I need to fill in the two arguments for TBase, I did something like this:

```
class MyContainer<T: TBase<T,F>, F: TFieldIdEnum>
```

However this requires me to write code like this:

```java
val msg = MyContainer<MyEvent, MyEvent._Fields>()
```

which I suppose works and otherwise gets me the functionality I need, but is there anyway I can more succinctly tell java "I need a T that implements TBase with type T and T._Fields"  so I can do `val msg = MyContainer<MyEvent>()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only a container, you can use star-projection:

```
class MyContainer<T: TBase<T,*>>
```

That will make `val msg = MyContainer<MyEvent>()` work. This technique is sometimes useful when you work with objects using reflection anyway, as is the case with Protobuf and Thrift.

But your question doesn't give hints as to how you plan to use this container.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to work (am new to Java/Kotlin). So to answer your question, I'm using a set of thrift generated classes, I'd like to add some convenience methods to them to do binary serialization/deserialization. I've read elsewhere that its recommended to not modify the auto-generated code and instead use a wrapper class; so this was my (possibly inefficient) approach. The container here just adds some additional methods that will work on any thrift generated class.

Comment: I did something very similar with Protobuf, and my recommendation to you would be to generate those wrapper classes. You may encounter limitations using this generics-based approach.